# vue I18n: How to make a beautiful drop-down list for changing the language

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

There is a project on vue.js to which the i18n library is connected.I have a drop-down list that switches languages

```
<template>
  <div class="locale-changer">
    <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
      <option
        v-for="(lang, i) in langs"
        :key="`Lang${i}`"
        :value="lang"
      >{{ lang }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'VeLanguageSwitcher',
  data () {
    return { langs: ['en-US', 'ru-RU'] }
  }
}
</script>
```

I need to make it beautiful by example
[image]

Help me please!!!

Comment: what do you really want ?

Comment: I don’t understand how to insert these flags

Comment: It's hard for you to create that kind of dropdown using select tag only. Yet possible but you will need more codes on it. I suggest you to do it using ul and li. This will solve your problem and handle easily some future feature on it.

Comment: Beautiful things are done with css. Add styles and css rules for your DOM.